# Is there any way to use AnyLogic traffic simulation by using GIS map without building all roads using "Road" from Road traffic library?

Tags: anylogic

I am working on traffic volume simulation model for big city. The simulation can be done perfectly by building roads using "Road" from Road traffic library. However, The simulation model is for big city and it is very hard to draw all roads with detailes. Is there is any way to simulate the traffic roads directly by GIS or any other way?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the answer to this question is no.

The road traffic library is not compatible with GIS features, nevertheless if you have a shapefile with the roads, you can transform it into the road traffic objects, but you will need to fix a lot of small details and add traffic lights in a very manual way.

You can also automate the creation of all your road objects on startup if you have a file that has all the definitions, but you will need to do a lot of advanced coding for this.

I have always been scared to do a project like this because even with small models, the creation of roads is very hard.

I would suggest also to look into other better traffic simulators such as SUMO, which I think is the most popular on the topic.

Comment: Or MatSim https://www.matsim.org/, which is also Java-based, and Open Source. I used it for my masters, there is tons of free stuff available to help you build models and you can also create some nice post model run animation. Most big transport simulation models don't have runtime animation as it is computationally to expensive.

Comment: here is a paper comparing matsim and sumo https://www.scitepress.org/Papers/2021/102383/102383.pdf

Comment: @Felipe
unfortunate anylogic has this limitation otherwise it is really strong simulation platform

Comment: @Jaco-BenVosloo
MatSim is good but there are other open source well-known platforms such as SUMO